# android: Cannot import SpeedScrollListener from cuubonandroid (sugaredlistanimations) proporly

Tags: android, jar

I'm trying to import the library from [cuubonandroid](https://github.com/cuub/sugared-list-animations-sample) to my application. I'm also using google-play-services_lib as well (this one is working fine).

Now how have I tried importing?
well I right-clicked on my project -> properties -> Android [tab]

scrolled down to "Libraries", then Add.... Oh i've imported the library to my 
workspace before doing that (and Yes I copied the files to the workspace folder too)

The errors were gone and I was able to use the classes in that other project. However, during run-time I'm getting this error:

```
08-21 21:18:03.530: E/dalvikvm(5281): Could not find class 'com.cuubonandroid.sugaredlistanimations.SpeedScrollListener', referenced from method <a method in my app>
```

I've also tried to including by going to: right-clicked on my project -> properties -> Java Build Path  and included a jar file i found in the bin folder of that project.
again, same thing. Compiled but produced same problem.

Have anyone worked with sugaredlistanimations library before?